# Wrap some specified words with span in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, highlight

I'd like to know the most convenient way to wrap some specified words with span-tags.

Example:
I have a word, which is dog. Here's the original text:

```
I have a dog, do you have a dog?
```

And output should be like this:

```
I have a <span class="highlight">dog</span>, do you have a <span class="highlight">dog</span>?
```

Any help?

**EDIT:**
Note, that it should also wrap words, even if they are not invidual (Peter-dog). Hope you got it.

Comment: please when asking questions, refrain from limiting your title to a jQuery solution, jQuery isn't a language, JS is, thus the solution should be in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a useful [jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html).

It's really easy to use and it works great.

*edit* — this is a very old answer of mine. I regret having simply linked the Lettering.js library without including its name. The library *is* useful, though I'm not sure here 7 years later whether Mr. Rupert continues to actively maintain it.

What Lettering does is go through the text nodes in a selected region of the DOM and wrap the individual letters and/or words (configurable) in `<span>` tags that can then be styled. It's simple but effective. Even if you don't want to use it, the code is not very extensive and it's instructional.

Comment: There's no need to use tinyurl on StackOverflow, that's what Markdown is for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [JavaScript replace function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).  Here is a basic example:

```
$('#container').html($('#container').html().replace(/(dog)/g,'<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
```

Comment: .val() should only work on form elements. You need .text() here - if I'm not wrong atm.

Comment: you are not wrong - this answer won't actually work given the original question, which is about words in running text, not in form elements. Even then, putting span tags inside form element values would not work anyway.

Comment: Actually, it's html().  Code fixed and tested.

Comment: html() and text() would both work fine. for the sake of clarity, you should rebuild this code to make it more readable by using variables, would be nice.

Comment: I'm also interested to know how to make this work using variables instead of hardcoded strings