# How to show mouseover tooltip on selected word on web page using javascript, conditionally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

How to show mouseover tooltip on selected word on web page using javascript? i want to set some conditions

For example:

If page has text `<p> I'm Web Designer </p>` inside `<div id=example>` then it should show tool tip on **Designer** but tooltip should not be shown for **designer** without adding any `span` to Designer and designer. i want to select autuomatically

I have to set include and exclude keywords to pick, or notpic tool tip . and matter of all tooltips for all i want to write in another html file not in same page.

Comment: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Answer (score 1):

```
    You have to do it using css and javascript but following is the simple thing you can do for same result.
<a  title="Designer" href="javascript:void(0);" >Designer</a>

    Designer
```

Comment: i don't want to add anything in html code. i can only add css and javascript to the page

Answer (score 1):

Use the following jQuery to wrap an anchor tag around the word "designer" (inspiration [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214794/wrap-some-specified-words-with-span-in-jquery)):

```
$('#example').html(
  $('#example')
    .html()
    .replace(
      /(designer)/g,
      '<a href="#" class="normalTip" title="Some Text">$1</a>'
    )
);
```

Then use (for example) the [aToolTip library](http://ara-abcarians.com/jquery/atooltip/) to display the tip.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2x6J/